# How do you kill the Windows Defender "has been turned off" boot message?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-defender

Whenever I boot Windows 7, I get the message that says Windows Defender has been turned off (because of Security Essentials). I want Windows Defender off, and I want the message to go away. How do I kill this boot message? I disabled the service, but no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Those whom would have you believe that you have to disable Windows Defender from within Defender itself and that "...No other way will actually completely remove the messages...,' I'm sorry but this is INCORRECT!

Yes, If Windows Defender is already On, then you should first Disable it from within the Defender console itself, however in many cases that simply isn't enough.

Once you are sure that Windows Defender is disabled from within the console itself, then proceed with the following steps below...

You can actually DISABLE Windows Defender service from starting up at all and that will get rid of the pesky "Windows Defender reports that the service is turned off" message at startup...

Simply type in [  services.msc   ] into the start box and locate Windows Defender on the list.

As soon as you find it, right-click it and click on Properties.

Under the "General" tab where it says "StartUp Type" with a drop-down menu next to it, click on the drop-down menu, select "Disabled" and then click apply at the bottom of that Window.

Exit the services and restart your pc. You should no longer notice that nagging message at startup.

Comment: Options to disable it in Services are grayed out in RTM, if you have pro you can disable it in group policy editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off Defender from within Defender.  No other way will actually completely remove the messages you indicate.  [See here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/03/11/how-to-disable-windows-defender-in-windows-7/)

I'll add though, that MSE and Defender work together nicely.  No need to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Since Windows Defender doesn't run, this doesn't help. Stopping the service did not get rid of the boot message.

Comment: @xpda - you need to enable the service and disable Defender as indicated in my answer.

Comment: When I tried that, Windows Defender would not run because of MSE, so I could not disable it from within Defender. Removing the registry setting prevents Windows Defender from trying to start in the first place.

Comment: @xpda - I'd uninstall MSE, undo the reg edits and service changes on Defender and reinstall MSE.  As indicated below MSE should disable Defender and MSE should be listed as your tool of choice under the Action Center heading 'Spyware and unwanted software protection'.

Answer (score 1):

Security Essentials turns off Windows Defender, so I have been getting that message. Windows Defender won't run.

I disabled all the messages in Action Center, but it didn't help. I checked System Configuration, Startup, and it's not listed there. But there was a Windows Defender Service. I disabled that. No Change.

Finally, I found Windows Defender listed in System Information, System Summary, Software Environment, Startup Programs, with a -hide flag:

```
Windows Defender    %programfiles%\windows defender\msascui.exe -hide    Public    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

I killed that key in the registry and that solved the program. The hide flag must be why it didn't show up in System Configuration and msconfig startup.

Answer (score 1):

After disabling "Windows Defender" in Services you need to remove it from Start Up options.

1. Go to your "Start button" menu and select the "run" tab and type "msconfig"
2. Select the "start up" tab,
3. un-check the "Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" "Windows Defender" which
   is the MSASCui.exe command that is causing this annoyance,
4. Click "Apply" your done this should sort the problem of nag at start up.

If you don't have the "Run" tab enabled in your "Start" menu simply right click "Start" button and select "properties", under "Start Munu" tab select "Customize" tab, scroll down to bottom of the list and make sure the box next to the "Run command" listing is ticked then click OK, now you have the "Run" tab enabled in "start" menu.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel (icon view) > Action Center, look under "Security" see if MSE is detected in two categories

Anti Virus and Spyware.

If it is not, that is the problem, I would uninstall MSE and try the MSE installer in administrator mode to install it again.

[image]